# Can't Find BBPress data in Database

Tags: buddypress, bbpress

I have installed BBPress in my Buddypress Based Wordpress Site. And i m unable to find any table of bbpress which contains data from the forum in my database.

Where can i find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know bbPress uses custom post types. So all the data are in the regular `posts` and `post_meta` tables. A look at the source code should tell you more.

From the [bbPress Codex](http://codex.bbpress.org/getting-started-with-bbpress/):

> bbPress creates three custom post types and adds them to the navigation menu: Forums, Topics, and Replies. Use these menu items to create and manage your forums.

Comment: just tested this, and you're right - I guess they've massively changed the way bbPress works since I last tried it out.